# Subdistrics border change over time

Tags: r, borders

I have 4 shapefiles of India state from 4 decades, and I trying to identify changes within the sub-district level such as splits or merge of sub-dist, border changes etc.

I am using R but I can use other packages such as ArcGIS...

Any suggestion how to check and measure the border change over time?

Comment: in ArcGIS see the [Analyzing differences between two shapefiles to put results into new shapefile?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54444/25060) article.